# view page is not showing the data passed from controller

Tags: java, jsp

i am unable to fetch data sent from controller and display on my jsp page.

payments.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>


<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Dashboard
            <small>Control panel</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Payments</li>
        </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
        <!-- Main row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form action="<c:url value="/getCandidateDetails"/>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="bank">Bank:</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" id="bank" path="bank" name="bank" 
                     class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="bank">Account No.</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" id="accountNo" path="accountNo"          
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="revenueHead">Revenue Head:</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" id="revenueHead" 
                 path="revenueHead" name="revenueHead" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="depositslipNo">Deposit Slip No.</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" id="depositslipNo" 
            path="depositslipNo" name="depositslipNo" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fiscalYear">FiscalYear:</label><br/>
                        <select name="fiscalYear" class="form-control">
                            <option value="2016/17">2016/17</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="masterId">Master Id:</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" id="masterId" 
         path="studentmasterid" name="studentmasterid" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
                  id="search" onclick="showDiv()">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="paymenttable" >
                <table class="table table-striped"  >
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Master Id:</th>
                        <th>Advertisement Code</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="payment" items="${details}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${payment.studentmasterid}</td>
                            <td>${payment.advertisementCode}</td>
                            <td>${payment.candidatefirstname}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<c:url 
          value="/paymentsDetails/allInfo/${payment.advertisementCode}"/> ">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                                </a>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row (main row) -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js">
```

mycontroller.java

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/getCandidateDetails", 
method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getCandidateDetails(Model model,@RequestParam("studentmasterid") String studentmasterid){
        System.out.println(studentmasterid);
        List<CandidateDetailsInfo> candidates= `candidateappearagainstadvtcodeEntityRepository.findAllByStudentmasterid(studentmasterid);`
        model.addAttribute("details",candidates);;
        return "payments";
    }
```

myrepository

```
public interface CandidateappearagainstadvtcodeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CandidateappearagainstadvtcodeEntity,Long> {

    @Query("select c from CandidateappearagainstadvtcodeEntity c where c.studentmasterid=?1")
    List<CandidateDetailsInfo> findAllByStudentmasterid(String masterId);

}
```

my repository successfully returns data from database as i can print them on console. but whenever i submit my form it page keeps loading forever.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hloi.png)

Comment: Your controller returns a String? How does the client know what to do with that? Shouldn't you be redirect to another HTML to display the results? If you want to work with JSON then you still need to write some Javascript to render the output.

Comment: payments is a jsp page.

Comment: You need to return a ModelAndView() with the jsp and model inside...Your using Spring MVC assumed?

Comment: the way i am doing also returns jsp page as it is configured on dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Let add a system.out.println() to the end of the controller method and see if the hang is with the repository or the controller. I believe the issue is with loading the view.

Comment: the problem is probably with view. i dont know i can only guess. console successfully prints the data.

Comment: I just consulted the Spring MVC tutorial, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm. You need to ensure the contextLoaderListener correctly defined and internalResourceViewResolver correctly setup.